How to keep custom view background static while making swipe to delete action
So I have this code:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var names = ["Ted", "Barney", "Lily", "Robin", "Marshal"]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(names, id: \.self) { name in
                ListRowView(name: name)
            }
            .onDelete(perform: deleteName)
        }
        .listStyle(.plain)
        .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
    }

    func deleteName(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        names.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    }
}

struct ListRowView: View {

    let name: String

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            iconView
            titleView
            Spacer()
        }
        .background(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                .fill(.purple)
        )
    }

    var titleView: some View {
        Text("\(name)")
            .foregroundStyle(.white)
    }


    var iconView: some View {
        Circle()
            .fill(Color.white.opacity(0.2))
            .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
            .padding()
    }
}

when I swipe to delete, it looks like this:

but I am trying to achieve something like this:

I want the red view that appears from the right when swiping to be a part of the row background. I'm not sure how to explain it better. Perhaps I'm applying the background view in the wrong way?

To achieve what you are looking for, you have to have custom cells with your own implementation for swipe to delete...

You can achieve a very close design using the native APIs by a combination of the Section and insetGrouped style list:

List {
    ForEach(names, id: \.self) { name in
        Section { //  Separate cells
            ListRowView(name: name)
        }
    }
    .onDelete(perform: deleteName)
    .listRowBackground(Color.purple) ///  Use a simple background color
    .listRowInsets(.init()) //  Fit the content to the edges of the cell
    .listSectionSpacing(16) //  Nicer spacing
}
.listStyle(.insetGrouped) //  Make the sections appear rounded
.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)


Yeah thanks, at it works as expected. I guess Section usage  can hardly be a problem later. Will see...
